# How to find the difference between two xml in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xslt which has a variable contains like this xml data

```
<reflection>
  <assemblies>... some data here..</assemblies>
<apis>
<api id="M:AdminService.AdminDetails.SetAdminRights(System.String)">
      <apidata name="SetAdminRights" group="member" subgroup="method" />
      <memberdata visibility="public" />
      <proceduredata virtual="false" />
      <parameters>
        <parameter name="rightsId">
          <type api="T:System.String" ref="true" />
        </parameter>
      </parameters>
      <returns>
        <type api="T:System.Boolean" ref="false" />
      </returns>
      <containers>
        <library assembly="AdminService" module="AdminService" kind="DynamicallyLinkedLibrary" />
        <namespace api="N:AdminService" />
        <type api="T:AdminService.AdminDetails" ref="true" />
      </containers>
    </api>

 ... many api tag like this.
</apis>
</reflection>
```

same like this data in another variable. Now i need to find out the api tag which has some differences (here all nodes under the api should be same and with same attributes and values. If any change then that api node needs to be filetered).

I tried with this

```
<xsl:for-each  select="apis/api[not(api = $baseline/reflection/apis/api)]">
```

this foreach loop is under   `<xsl:template match="/reflection">`. No luck. Its not giving the proper data.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 (available for .NET from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/ and also from NuGet) or XmlPrime you could use

```
<xsl:for-each select="apis/api[not($someApi in $baseline/reflection/apis/api satisfies deep-equal(., $someApi))]">
```

With XSLT 1.0 it is difficult to express that condition in a single XPath predicate as `deep-equal` is not supported in XSLT/XPath 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will look into it